# How to change height and width of camera view(UIImagePickerViewController) iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, camera, ios-camera

I want to show camera in rectangle shape as a part of `UItableViewCell` to scan numbers.

How to change size of `UIImagePickerViewController` and add it as a `subview`?

Answer (score 1):

You can either add the `UIImagePickerViewController` as `childViewController` and add its view as subview to your cell (make sure you don;t repeat it on reuse), or you can do your scanner with `AVFoundation`, and add the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` as sublayer to your view's layer.
I would chose the latter.